# I'm creating an HTML table with vertical text but I'm having trouble ajusting width to minimize empty space

Tags: html, css

This is the table I'm creating. It can be noted there is too much empty space to either side of "A few words". I would like to adjust width so it keeps showing the whole text but with less empty space.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn9Kk.png)

```css
table { border: 0px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse; } table td {
    border: 1px solid #000; padding: 12px; } .rotate { white-space:nowrap;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg); writing-mode: lr-tb; }
```

```html
    
      <table align="center" border="1">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><b><br>
                  </b> </td>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><b>Text<br>
                    </b></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><b>Text</b></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><b>Text</b></span></td>
                <td><b>Text</b></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" class="rotate"><b>A few words<br>
                    </b></span></td>
                <td><b>Text</b></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text<span style="color:blue;"></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><b>Text<br>
                    </b></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><b>Text</b></span></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size:140%;">Text</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust the td using max-width. I also removed the padding and used translateX to move the rotated text a little bit in the snippet below:

```css
    .rotate { 
        white-space:nowrap;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%); 
        writing-mode: lr-tb; 
        max-width: 30px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!